# Division of integers with odd numbers

Tags: swift

```
var number = numberCars/ (categories?.count)!
```

`numberCars` is the number of cars, `categories?.count` the number of cars categories and `number` is number of cars assigned to each category, so for example if `numberCars = 4` and `categories?.count = 2` 4/2 = 2 we'll have assigned 2 cars for category. Unfortunately this work only if i have even numbers, how can i do in situation like `numberCars = 7` and `categories?.count = 3` ? In this case i would like to assign 3 cars to one category and 2 cars to the remaining ones.

Comment: Look into the remainder operator (`%`).

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: This has nothing to do with odd numbers. Consider 4 categories and 10 cars, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you've `numberOfCars` variable in `Category` object then you can use simple arithmetic to calculate your requirement. This code is not optimised you can optimise this code of you want to. This is just giving you idea how you can do it

```
let number = numberCars/categories.count
let remainder = numberCars % categories.count


print("avg cars:\(number) remainder:\(remainder)")

// Assign the avg cars to all category
for category in categories {
  category.numberOfCars = number
}

// Increment the categories to fit the remaining cars
for i in 0..<remainder {
  categories[i].numberOfCars += 1
}


for category in categories {
  print("# cars \(category.numberOfCars)")
}
```

Comment: i can't do category.numberOfCars because numberOfCars is not in category object, numberOfCars is a simple Int, var numberOfCars = 0

Comment: My code was to jist give you the idea of how you can achieve it. Please modify this code accordingly

Comment: i understand what i have to do about the cycle but how can i replace category.numberOfCars with what i need, considering numberOfCars is just a simple Int ?

Answer (score 0):

Optimised Code.

```
let remainder = numberCars % categories.count

if numberCars > categories.count {
  // Assign the avg cars to all category
  for category in categories {
    category.numberOfCars = categories.count
  }
}

// Increment the categories to fit the remaining cars
for i in 0..<remainder {
  categories[i].numberOfCars += 1
}


for category in categories {
  print("# cars \(category.numberOfCars)")
}
```

Comment: i can't do category.numberOfCars because numberOfCars is not in category object

Comment: numberOfCars is a simple Int, var numberOfCars = 0